# OpenLayers PanZoomBar css style

Tags: openlayers-2

I need to use PanZoomBar in my application.

```
var panZoomBar = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar();
map.addControl(panZoomBar);
```

Also I need to overwrite the PanZoomBar css style. I overwrite the whole bar.

```
.olControlPanZoomBar {
    top: 38px !important;
    left: 18px !important;
    width: 44px;
    height: 214px;
    background: transparent url(../images/zoombar_bg.png) no-repeat 50% 100%;
}
```

But how I can get access and overwrite the default buttons? I mean:

```
.whatName(Id)ShowIWriteHere {
    some style
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default buttons are images, not html/css elements.

Your only options are to edit the images directly. They will be located here: `openlayers/theme/default/img`

Or you can download the images from the git source directly and then make modifications as you wish here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/tree/master/theme/default/img

Another method would be to use someone else's navigation images, like https://github.com/developmentseed/openlayers_themes/tree/master/dark

Or you can build on top of developmentseed's source vector graphics and create your own!! https://github.com/developmentseed/openlayers_themes/tree/master/dark_src

Good luck!